# How to get zoom level of mapview on touch event in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

In my program I used,

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
     {
         int currentLevel=mapView.getZoomLevel();
         return false;
     }
}
```

It gives me current level on touch event initially....But,when I click on zoom control bar, then Touch event won't work.
How can I get zoom level after click on zoom control bar.?

Please give me some solution.

Comment: `mapView.getZoomLevel()` instead of `mapKeyword.getZoomLevel()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private MapController mc;
```

Then when you use Overlays then use this

```
p = new GeoPoint((int) (toLat * 1E6), (int) (toLon * 1E6));    
mc.animateTo(p);
mc.setZoom(15);
```

You can refer these Two examples. , [Example 1](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android),[Example 2](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/04/google-map-example-in-android-with-info.html)